# Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,256,256] rhs shape= [1,1,1280,256] [[Node: save/Assign_348

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train a SSD Lite + MobileNetv2 using the model_main.py in the tensorflow/models/research/objectdetection but I'm getting the following error

```
Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,256,256] rhs shape= [1,1,1280,256] [[Node: save/Assign_348 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/weights"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/weights, save/RestoreV2:348)]]
```

The full log is given here,

```
python E:\Documents\Projects\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main.py --alsologtostderr --pipeline_config_path=experiments/training_/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco.config --model_dir=experiments/training_/ --num_train_steps=50000 --NUM_EVAL_STEPS=2000
WARNING:tensorflow:Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
W1123 09:11:18.686478 7432 tf_logging.py:125] Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
WARNING:tensorflow:Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs = 0. Overwriting num_epochs to 1.
W1123 09:11:18.687448 7432 tf_logging.py:125] Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs = 0. Overwriting num_epochs to 1.
WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator's model_fn (<function create_model_fn..model_fn at 0x000001E641D31268>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
W1123 09:11:18.688472 7432 tf_logging.py:125] Estimator's model_fn (<function create_model_fn..model_fn at 0x000001E641D31268>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
2018-11-23 09:11:23.084879: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-11-23 09:11:23.365711: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1392] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.835
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 6.00GiB freeMemory: 4.97GiB
2018-11-23 09:11:23.372771: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1471] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-11-23 09:11:24.001841: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:952] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-11-23 09:11:24.004967: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:958] 0
2018-11-23 09:11:24.007058: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971] 0: N
2018-11-23 09:11:24.009175: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1084] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4741 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,256,256] rhs shape= [1,1,1280,256]
[[Node: save/Assign_348 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/weights"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/weights, save/RestoreV2:348)]]
[[Node: save/RestoreV2/_599 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_728_save/RestoreV2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Documents\Projects\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main.py", line 109, in 
tf.app.run()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
File "E:\Documents\Projects\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main.py", line 105, in main
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 447, in train_and_evaluate
return executor.run()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 531, in run
return self.run_local()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 681, in run_local
eval_result, export_results = evaluator.evaluate_and_export()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 886, in evaluate_and_export
hooks=self._eval_spec.hooks)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 460, in evaluate
output_dir=self.eval_dir(name))
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1386, in _evaluate_run
config=self._session_config)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\evaluation.py", line 209, in _evaluate_once
session_creator=session_creator, hooks=hooks) as session:
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 826, in init
stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 549, in init
self._sess = _RecoverableSession(self._coordinated_creator)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1012, in init
_WrappedSession.init(self, self._create_session())
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1017, in _create_session
return self._sess_creator.create_session()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 706, in create_session
self.tf_sess = self._session_creator.create_session()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 477, in create_session
init_fn=self._scaffold.init_fn)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\session_manager.py", line 281, in prepare_session
config=config)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\session_manager.py", line 195, in _restore_checkpoint
saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_filename_with_path)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1752, in restore
{self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 900, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1135, in _run
feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
run_metadata)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,256,256] rhs shape= [1,1,1280,256]
[[Node: save/Assign_348 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/weights"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/weights, save/RestoreV2:348)]]
[[Node: save/RestoreV2/_599 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_728_save/RestoreV2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]

Caused by op 'save/Assign_348', defined at:
File "E:\Documents\Projects\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main.py", line 109, in 
tf.app.run()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
File "E:\Documents\Projects\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main.py", line 105, in main
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 447, in train_and_evaluate
return executor.run()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 531, in run
return self.run_local()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 681, in run_local
eval_result, export_results = evaluator.evaluate_and_export()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 886, in evaluate_and_export
hooks=self._eval_spec.hooks)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 460, in evaluate
output_dir=self.eval_dir(name))
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1386, in _evaluate_run
config=self._session_config)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\evaluation.py", line 209, in _evaluate_once
session_creator=session_creator, hooks=hooks) as session:
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 826, in init
stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 549, in init
self._sess = _RecoverableSession(self._coordinated_creator)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1012, in init
_WrappedSession.init(self, self._create_session())
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1017, in _create_session
return self._sess_creator.create_session()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 706, in create_session
self.tf_sess = self._session_creator.create_session()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 468, in create_session
self._scaffold.finalize()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 212, in finalize
self._saver = training_saver._get_saver_or_default() # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 856, in _get_saver_or_default
saver = Saver(sharded=True, allow_empty=True)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1284, in init
self.build()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1296, in build
self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1333, in _build
build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 775, in _build_internal
restore_sequentially, reshape)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 453, in _AddShardedRestoreOps
name="restore_shard"))
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 422, in _AddRestoreOps
assign_ops.append(saveable.restore(saveable_tensors, shapes))
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 113, in restore
self.op.get_shape().is_fully_defined())
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\state_ops.py", line 219, in assign
validate_shape=validate_shape)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_state_ops.py", line 63, in assign
use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
op_def=op_def)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
op_def=op_def)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1740, in init
self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack() # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,256,256] rhs shape= [1,1,1280,256]
[[Node: save/Assign_348 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/weights"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/weights, save/RestoreV2:348)]]
[[Node: save/RestoreV2/_599 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_728_save/RestoreV2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]
```

My config can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/zubairahmed-ai/489ff298a221ab5e44b2855996cacb5e)

Also note that I originally [posted it on Tensorflow/models/issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5806) but the team suggested that I post here on SO

Comment: Have you properly resized your image? That's often the problem when sizes don't match up.

Comment: No my images are in 5 different sets of dimensions 
409x728,436x728, 546x728,728x409, 728x546,728x970

Comment: The images were used to train a Faster RCNN model earlier

Answer (score 1):

The error disappeared after I upgraded to TF 1.12 and cuDNN 7.3 for my CUDA v9

Answer (score 1):

**This is the command, customise it according to the parameters used in training.**

python deeplab/export_model.py --checkpoint_path=/code/models/research/deeplab/weights_input_level_17/model.ckpt-22000 --export_path=/code/models/research/deeplab/frozen_weights_level_17/frozen_inference_graph.pb --model_variant="xception_65" --atrous_rates=6 --atrous_rates=12 --atrous_rates=18 --output_stride=16 --crop_size=2048 --crop_size=2048 --num_classes=3

I trained my model to segment bridges and followed the pascal dataset format. So ideally I had only one class but since we have two default classes 1. Background 2.Ignore class and 3.Bridge so my total classes become 3.

Hey, Guys please use this config to export your deeplabv3plus mode. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Your error is because of the dimensions in your image, you should make them equal as the ones you used for training